# Django YouTube API Upload fails with iPhone

Tags: python, django, youtube

I can upload videos to YouTube through my Django application, but only when they are uploaded from my laptop. YouTube gives me a "Processing abandoned" error when I upload the same video through my iPhone.

I am running Ubuntu 16.04.3 with Django version 1.11.20 and Python 2.7. I am using a function in my views to receive the uploaded file, and, if it is over 2.5 megabytes, grab the file from the /tmp directory, and if it is under 2.5 megabytes, process the file from memory.

This works when I upload video files from my laptop, but it fails when I upload video files from my iPhone.

To be clear, I don't get errors from Django/Python. The file seems to upload, process, and delete just fine. But after YouTube receives it, I go into my YouTube Studio, and it gives me a "Processing abandoned. This video could not be processed," error.

```
def upload_to_youtube(request):
    if request.method == 'POST' and request.FILES['video']:
        video_file = request.FILES['video']
        if video_file.size >= 2621440:
            fname = request.FILES['video'].file.name
            storage = DjangoORMStorage(CredentialsModel, 'id', request.user.id, 'credential')
            credentials = storage.get()
            client = build('youtube', 'v3', credentials=credentials)

            body = {...}

        with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile('wb', suffix='yt-django') as tmpfile:
        with open(fname, 'rb') as fileobj:
            tmpfile.write(fileobj.read())
            insert_request = client.videos().insert(
                        part=','.join(body.keys()),
            body=body,
            media_body=MediaFileUpload(
                tmpfile.name, chunksize=-1, resumable=True)
            )
            insert_request.execute()
    else:
            storage = DjangoORMStorage(CredentialsModel, 'id', request.user.id, 'credential')
            credentials = storage.get()
            client = build('youtube', 'v3', credentials=credentials)

            body = {...}

            with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile('wb', suffix='yt-django') as tmpfile:
                tmpfile.write(request.FILES['video'].read())
        insert_request = client.videos().insert(
            part=','.join(body.keys()),
                body=body,
            media_body=MediaFileUpload(
            tmpfile.name, chunksize=-1, resumable=True)
        )
        insert_request.execute()
```

Originally thinking it was due to the file size, I wrote in a check to handle the file differently if it was 2.5 mb or less, to handle it from memory instead. However, even with a <2.5mb file sent from the laptop, it will still upload just fine. I am not sure if there is something in my Django/Python code that is problematic for iOS uploads, or if this is on YouTube's end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK it looks like I figured it out. Following YouTube's developer notes, I moved the actual video upload from my server to YouTube's to its own function, which would give me any errors that it was having. I haven't gotten any errors, but it's worked ever since. Here is the new code:

```
    if request.method == 'POST' and request.FILES['video']:
        video_file = request.FILES['video']
        if video_file.size >= 2621440:
            fname = request.FILES['video'].file.name
            messages.success(request, "Equal to or over 2.5 megabytes, saving to disk and uploading")
            storage = DjangoORMStorage(CredentialsModel, 'id', request.user.id, 'credential')
            credentials = storage.get()
            client = build('youtube', 'v3', credentials=credentials)

            body = {
                'snippet': {
                    'title': 'Upload Youtube Video',
                    'description': 'Video Description',
                    'tags': 'django,howto,video,api',
                    'categoryId': '27'
                },
                'status': {
                    'privacyStatus': 'unlisted'
                }
            }

            with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile('wb', suffix='yt-django') as tmpfile:
                with open(fname, 'rb') as fileobj:
                    tmpfile.write(fileobj.read())
                    insert_request = client.videos().insert(
                        part=','.join(body.keys()),
                        body=body,
                        media_body=MediaFileUpload(
                            tmpfile.name, chunksize=-1, resumable=True)
                    )
                    resumable_upload(insert_request)
        else:
            messages.success(request, "Under 2.5 megabytes, uploading from memory")
            storage = DjangoORMStorage(CredentialsModel, 'id', request.user.id, 'credential')
            credentials = storage.get()
            client = build('youtube', 'v3', credentials=credentials)

            body = {
                'snippet': {
                    'title': 'Upload Youtube Video',
                    'description': 'Video Description',
                    'tags': 'django,howto,video,api',
                    'categoryId': '27'
                },
                'status': {
                    'privacyStatus': 'unlisted'
                }
            }

            with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile('wb', suffix='yt-django') as tmpfile:
                tmpfile.write(request.FILES['video'].read())
                insert_request = client.videos().insert(
                    part=','.join(body.keys()),
                    body=body,
                    media_body=MediaFileUpload(
                        tmpfile.name, chunksize=-1, resumable=True)
                )
                resumable_upload(insert_request)

def resumable_upload(request):
    httplib2.RETRIES = 1
    MAX_RETRIES = 10
    RETRIABLE_EXCEPTIONS = (httplib2.HttpLib2Error, IOError, httplib.NotConnected, httplib.IncompleteRead, 
        httplib.ImproperConnectionState, httplib.CannotSendRequest, httplib.CannotSendHeader, httplib.ResponseNotReady, 
        httplib.BadStatusLine)
    RETRIABLE_STATUS_CODES = [500, 502, 503, 504]

    response = None
    error = None
    retry = 0
    while response is None:
        try:
            print 'Uploading file...'
            status, response = request.next_chunk()
            if response is not None:
                if 'id' in response:
                    print 'Video id "%s" was successfully uploaded.' % response['id']
                else:
                    exit('The upload failed with an unexpected response: %s' % response)
        except HTTPError, e:
            if e.resp.status in RETRIABLE_STATUS_CODES:
                error = 'A retriable HTTP error %d occurred:\n%s' % (e.resp.status, e.content)
            else:
                raise
        except RETRIABLE_EXCEPTIONS, e:
            error = 'A retriable error occurred: %s' % e

        if error is not None:
            print error
            retry += 1
            if retry > MAX_RETRIES:
                exit('No longer attempting to retry.')

            max_sleep = 2 ** retry
            sleep_seconds = random.random() * max_sleep
            print 'Sleeping %f seconds and then retrying...' % sleep_seconds
            time.sleep(sleep_seconds)
```